# WinForms library for funny or extravagant progress bars

Tags: windows, library, software-development

I'm looking for a collection of non-standard progress bars. My intended use is in games for little children (age 3 to 10) (feel free to suggest others libraries as well).

The library should

- be for .NET 4 (and higher)
- be for WinForms
- allow commercial use
- cost less than 75 € (one time fee, no annual cost)
- have a per developer license or even more permissive (not machine bound)

Please don't suggest to implement it myself. I know it's quite simple. This is not a matter of complexity but of creativity. I'd like to see the different ideas behind the progress bars. It might happen that I finally don't use the library in my application (but I'd still buy it to support the developers).

Example:

[image: Progress bar example]

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion [ProgressBarAdv for Windows Forms](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/progressbaradv) supports creating custom animations. Here is an [example](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/147136/ze/ProgressBarAdv_Customization1393009503).

You need Syncfusion Essential Studio to be installed for the sample to work.

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [syncfusion.com](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/147136/1744016961_c05649a7.PNG))</sub>

•be for .NET 4 (and higher): Yes

•be for WinForms: Yes

•allow commercial use: Yes -the community license also supports commercial use

•cost less than 75 € (one time fee, no annual cost):No, if you don't qualify for the community license

•have a per developer license or even more permissive (not machine bound): License is per developer and not machine bound

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: You (Syncfusion) should work on that linked page. Those progress bar examples are not visually appealing and violate against graphical design rules. *shudder* The airplane example is *much* better.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The website page for ProgressBarAdv is being improved and the non-standard images will be changed within the next few days.